# From Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,object>>> to Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,object,AnEnum>>> with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, tuples

Let's say I have a `Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,object>>> d`. How could I create with LINQ, from `d`, a `Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,object,AnEnum>>> d'` (where `AnEnum` is an `enum`) such that each `AnEnum` from `Tuple<string,object,AnEnum>` is determined by conditions on the `<Tuple<string,object>` ?

*Remark.* It's indeed quite a nested structure. Just to explain : in my world there are products that are caracterized by id's (`int`'s), and that have fields (named with `string`'s) whose values are either numeric of `string`'s -- hence the `object` in the `Tuple`'s. I have an api that to a list of id's `List<int>` and a list of fields `List<string>` associates a `Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,object>>>`. According to the values of certains fields, I can know which "type" of product I am dealing with, type that I flag with an `enum`.

Comment: Maybe you should make a class from whatever inside the `Tuple`

Comment: Oh wow, that's a crazy nested structure!

Comment: @Guy How would a class help me ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj For starters readability, you can hold `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>` instead of that complex structure. In your case it will be much easier to add an `enum`, just add another field. And it will be more appropriate to use class, after all C# is object oriented language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm maybe something like this:

```
d.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, 
               pair => pair.Value.Select(tuple => 
                              tuple.Create(tuple.Item1,
                                           tuple.Item2,                                                                                                     
                                           ConvertToEnum(tuple))).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thx, it helped me.